# Query to get all users that have logged in within the last 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL db `users` table that has a column called `lastLogin` this is just a simple timestamp to indicate when a user has last logged into the system.

e.g

| id | name | lastLogin | accountId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | bob | 1639572638 | 4 |
| 3 | tim | 1639572638 | 4 |
| 3 | ant | 1639572638 | 5 |
| 4 | leroy | 1339572638 | 6 |

expected results

| accountId | activeUsers |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 |

My current query returns 0 rows but not sure why

```
SELECT accountId, from_unixtime(lastLogin) as lastlogin, count(distinct(id)) as activeUsers 
FROM user 
HAVING lastlogin > now() - INTERVAL 30 day 
ORDER BY lastlogin desc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i figured it out hopefully helps someone else -

```
SELECT accountId,count(distinct(id)) as activeUsers 
FROM user 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(lastlogin) > now() - INTERVAL 30 day 
GROUP BY accountId;
```

Comment: Your use of `count(distinct(id))` is not correct. `DISTINCT` is not a function but a row qualifier; the parenthesis are not needed and there should be a space in it, as in `count(distinct id)`.

Comment: This query doesn't produce the expected result in the question.

Answer (score 4):

```sql
SELECT accountId, 
       FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(lastlogin)) lastlogin,  -- not listed in desired output
                                                 -- but present in the query
       SUM(lastlogin > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY)) activeUsers 
FROM user
GROUP BY accountId
```

For `distinct id` use

```sql
SELECT accountId, 
       FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(lastlogin)) lastlogin,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN lastlogin > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN id END) activeUsers  
FROM user
GROUP BY accountId
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f754e9ed49d872d0d68173a803f96126

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with u as
(select accountId, count(distinct id) as activeUsers from user
group by accountId
having FROM_UNIXTIME(max(lastlogin)) > now() - INTERVAL 30 day),
v as
(select distinct accountId from user)
(select v.accountId, coalesce(u.activeUsers, 0) as activeUsers from v left join 
u on v.accountId = u.accountId)
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ff547a4cde0c9bb13e5eecbe7e402f4)

Comment: The query counts total rows amount, not `DISTINCT id`. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f057d5c5ec21dc55f978fa229390bb6a

Comment: @Akina You're right, should be count(distinct id). Fixed it!